# Link to another page and call onclick function

Tags: html, hyperlink, onclick

I have a detailed product page where the following link loads a form and scrolls to it.

```
<a href="#leave-review" onclick="leaveReview();">Write a review</a>
... 
<div name="leave-review"></div>
```

I now have a list page where I want to have link "Write a review" that opens the detailed page and acts as if the upper link is clicked (loads the form and scrolls to it). How can I do that?

Comment: are u trying to make it like index work just like we click on chapter 14 and chapter 14 opens

Comment: Can't you just use an anchor tag?  If the target page has: `<a name="leave-review"></a>` then linking to `targetPage.html#leave-review` should take the user to that anchor.  JavaScript isn't necessary.

Comment: I can use anchor but it points to <div> which is empty by default and opens with a script